# mysqldump error 2003 Can't connect to MySQL server ... (110)

Tags: mysql, connection-timeout

I don't think this is a dup question as I have read other posts about error 2003 and none resolve my situation.

I have a bash script that executes mysqldump on a nightly basis against many tables in an Amazon RDS database.  It has worked without issue for months, but recently, I've started seeing errors.  Example results for a recent week:

```
Day 1:  success
Day 2:  success
Day 3:
   TBL citygrid_state:  export entire table
   TBL ci_sessions:  export entire table
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blah' (110) when trying to connect
... wrlog crit forced halt
Day 4:  success
Day 5:
   TBL sparefoot.consumer_lead_action_meta:  export entire table
   TBL sparefoot.consumer_lead_action_type:  export entire table
mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blah' (110) when trying to connect
... wrlog crit forced halt
```

Since the script works completely some nights and the calls to mysqldump work dozens of times before an error occurs, my thought is that I have a timeout problem.  But where?  Might it be a MySQL setting? Or does the issue lie elsewhere?

Some of the MySQL timeout settings:

```
   connect_timeout         10
   interactive_timeout     14400
   net_read_timeout        30
   net_write_timeout       60
   wait_timeout            28800
```

Comment: Each table is going to a different dump file........and yes, all dump files are perfect except the one it fails on (on the days it fails).  That dump file is empty.

Comment: hardware?  no idea, tis Amazon RDS.......
MySQL version 5.6.23........
Engine:  InnoDB........
size of the tables?  from 5 rows to a few dozen, none are huge

Comment: This is all I know about the hardware:
Machine class:  db.r3.4xlarge, Memory Optimized - Current Generation........
Number of virtual cores:  16 vCPU...........
Memory:   122 GiB........
EBS Optimized:  2000 Mbps.........
Network Performance:   High..........
Other activity:  mainly the backup.  The errors have occured *during* the backup and sometimes long *before* the backup starts.